# Flutter Isolate doesn't go do setState after navigate to a other page and back

Tags: android, flutter, dart, setstate, dart-isolates

Hello I have a badge with a counter and whenever I start my Android Alarm Manager it should increase the counter and also update the UI live. I do this with Isolate. Everything works fine but when I go to a new page route and then go back the SetState is not executed anymore. Where is my error?

```
  int _counter = 0;

  String isolateName = 'isolate';
  final ReceivePort port = ReceivePort();
  static SendPort uiSendPort;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();

    IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(
      port.sendPort,
      isolateName,
    );

    port.listen((_) async => await _incrementCounter());
  }

  Future<void> _incrementCounter() async {
    print('Increment counter!');

    // Ensure we've loaded the updated count from the background isolate.
    await prefs.reload();

    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      print("geht in die SetState");
      _counter++;
    });
  }

///
///This is in my Callback for my Android Alarm Manager...
          final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          int currentCount = prefs.getInt(countKey) ?? 0;
          await prefs.setInt(countKey, currentCount + 1);

          // This will be null if we're running in the background.
          uiSendPort ??= IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName('isolate');
          uiSendPort?.send(null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`initState` is not called again after returning, try to force the function you want after returning

something like that

```
Navigator.of(context)
  .push(MaterialPageRoute(
     builder: (context) => YourScreen№2(),
  ))
  .then((value) {
    Foo() <- your func
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you mean by force the function after returning?

Comment: I did edit answer

Comment: I mean this code in `initState`
`void initState() {
    super.initState();
    AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();

    IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(
      port.sendPort,
      isolateName,
    );

    port.listen((_) async => await _incrementCounter());
  }`

Comment: Okay thank you that worked but just with `Navigator.of(context).push`. Is it at also possible to get the same result with `Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => My2Site(),),(_) => false);` ?

Comment: seems ye, more here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushAndRemoveUntil.html#:~:text=Returns%20a%20Future%20that%20completes%20to%20the%20result%20value%20passed%20to%20pop%20when%20the%20pushed%20route%20is%20popped%20off%20the%20navigator

Comment: But why delete the previous screens if you want to return to them?